# Multiple instances of Word after running program

Tags: vb.net, ms-office

Does anyone know why I am getting a background process of word running in task manager for each time this goes round the for next loop? Thanks.

```
Try
        For Each element In Raneeded
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(element) Then
                Dim OpenRA = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

                docname = d(CInt(element)) & ".docx"
                OpenRA.Documents.Open(folderpath & docname)

                OpenRA.Visible = False
                Dim opened1 = OpenRA.ActiveDocument

                Dim RAtable As Word.Table = opened1.Tables(1)
                RAtable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Site Address: " & address
                opened1.Close()
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & " Please contact your system Administrator, quoting these details.")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close the doc, but never close the word aplication OpenRA, either define it outside the loop, and close it at the end, or close each one when you close the doc

```
 opened1.Save()
 OpenRA.Quit()
```

Comment: Great thank you, Im very new to the Office.Interop sections. Just for the reference, the .Close() command does not work for Office Apps, It works fine without it

Comment: @Joe This code does not release the objects and might continue having opened Word instances. Safest way is making both objects null (opened1.Save() opened1 = Nothing OpenRA.Quit() and OpenRA = Nothing). Also bear in mind that these rules only apply to Word; killing all the live instances of Excel, for example, is more difficult (you would have to do some research on this).